# Difference between .group {} and .group a {}

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS. Can somebody tell the difference between .group {} and .group a {}? Thank you very much! [HTML] [CSS]

Comment: I think you need to learn the basics first! Try on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). In sort answer there are selectors in CSS rules that find in the DOM for elements that fit that selector. Like an `a` element wich has a parent of another element with `group` class

Comment: I'm afraid @frikinside is right. This site is not meant for learning about stuff; we are not teachers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.group {}` will target elements with class `group` and `.group a {}` will target `<a>` elements which are in element with class `group`

Comment: ..elements which are *descendants of*.. (not merely "in" or "children of")

Comment: sure, "children of" is another selector, but "in" doesnt mean children, but "in" is unclear, my bad

Answer (score 2):

`.group` means all elements with class "group"
`.group a` means all `a` descendant elements of elements having class "group"
`.group>a` means all `a` child elements of elements having class "group"

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you didn't get that, `.group {}` and `.group a {}` are for 2 different things.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="group">
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

`.group {}` would be modifying `<div>` and `.group a {}` would be modifying all the `<a>` tags that are included in that div

Comment: "are two different classes" — No, they aren't. They aren't classes at all. They both include a class *selector* (which is the same class selector in each case).